# Probability that fewer than $50$ out of $200$ files get damaged if they get damaged at a rate of $0.2$?

Tags: probability, statistics

**A new computer virus attacks a folder consisting of 200 files. Each
gets damaged with probability $0.2$ independently of other files. What is the
probability that fewer than $50$ files get damaged?**

I need help for this question. Does anyone please can provide the answer for me as step-by-step?

Sorry and thank you :(

Comment: What have you tried so far? This website is here to help you if you get stuck on something but it's not supposed to be a place where people solve your homework for you. If you tell us what you've tried, we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.**  $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 200, p =.2)$ counts damaged files.

**Step 2.**  You seek $P(X < 50) = P(X \le 49).$

**Step 3.**  Find the numerical value of probability in Step 2. Perhaps you are
supposed to use a normal approximation and perhaps to use software for
an exact answer. You have provided no context, so I can't say which.

*Notes:* (1) The average number of files damaged is $\mu = np = 40$ 
and $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)} \approx 5.66,$ so you might guess the probability is considerably more than 1/2. (2) Using software, I get $P(X < 50) \approx .95,$ I hope you can finish this problem with this start.